# Can I use an upper semi-circle to integrate this function?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm trying to integrate

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{iz}}{e^z + e^{-z}}dz$$

Do I have have to integrate this over a box, or can I use my first guess at a contour and use an upper semi-circle just fine?

On the semi-circle, I have the estimate:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{iz}}{e^z + e^{-z}}dz$$

$$\le \pi R \frac{|e^{iz}|}{|e^z + e^{-z}|}$$

$$\le \frac {\pi R} {|e^z + e^{-z}|}$$

$$\le \frac {\pi R} {|e^z|}$$

and I'm not sure how to treat the denominator.  I want to show the last term goes to zero, as we let R go to infinity, so that I can just look at the integral over the straight line on the real axis, from -R to R.

Of course, on the semi-circle, the parametrization is $z=Re^{i\theta}$, with $\theta$ ranging from 0 to $\pi$.

A student solution integrates over a suitably chosen box, but I wouldn't have came up with that myself, so I'm wondering whether I could still make it work with my choice of an upper semi-circle.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you're missing $\mathrm{d}z$ from your integrals.

Comment: Yes, thanks @FlybyNight - I will edit now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your estimates are wrong.  $|e^{iz}| = 1$ when $z$ is real, but not on the semicircle.  Moreover, the denominator is not so easy to estimate: for example when $z=iy$ is imaginary, $e^z + e^{-z} = 2 \cos(y)$, and this can be $0$ which you need to avoid.

Comment: I might be wrong, but $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}z}=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(x+\mathrm{i}y)}=\mathrm{e}^{-y}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}$ and so we have $|\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}z}| =  |\mathrm{e}^{-y}\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}| = |\mathrm{e}^{-y}|\,|\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}| = |\mathrm{e}^{-y}|.$ On the upper semi-circle we have $0 \le y \le R$ meaning that $\mathrm{e}^{-R} \le |\mathrm{e}^{-y}| \le \mathrm{e}^0$. So $|\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}z}| \le 1$.

Comment: Thanks so much, Professor Israel - I will re-do the problem now.  I was indeed forgetting that $|e^{iz}|$ = 1 for z *real* (and of course struggling with how to treat the denominator.)

Answer (score 3):

How about considering the positively oriented rectangle $Q_R$, where $R>0$, with vertices $-R$, $+R$, $2\pi\text{i}+R$, and $2\pi\text{i}-R$?  You should find that there are two poles $\frac{\pi \text{i}}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi\text{i}}{2}$ of $f(z):=\frac{\exp(\text{i}z)}{\exp(z)+\exp(-z)}$ enclosed by $Q_R$ for each $R>0$.  If $I$ is the required integral, then taking $R\to\infty$, we have
$$\big(1-\exp(-2\pi)\big)\,I=2\pi\text{i}\left(\text{Res}_{z=\frac{\pi \text{i}}{2}}\big(f(z)\big)+\text{Res}_{z=\frac{3\pi \text{i}}{2}}\big(f(z)\big)\right)\,.$$
The final answer should be
$$I=\frac{\pi\,\big(\exp(-\pi/2)-\exp(-3\pi/2)\big)}{1-\exp(-2\pi)}=\frac{\pi}{\exp(+\pi/2)+\exp(-\pi/2)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\,.$$

Why is this box $Q_R$ good, but not a semicircle with radius $R$?  That is because, as $R\to\infty$, the semicircle encloses more and more poles of $f(z)$, making the calculation more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Batominovski - I arrived at the correct solution, but I instead used R + i$\pi$ to compute just one less residue.  Also, your answer and @RobertIsrael's answer helped me better visualize where the poles were -- along the imaginary axis with y >0.  So, the choice of this box makes the contour grow to infinity while still just enclosing the one pole -- the box grows in length but stays fixed in its width :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathcal{L}(\cos z)=\frac{s}{s^2+1}$,
$$I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos z}{\cosh z}\,dz=2\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(2k+1)(-1)^k}{1+(2k+1)^2}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{2k+1-i}+\frac{1}{2k+1+i}\right)(-1)^k $$
but since:
$$ \text{Res}\left(\sec\frac{\pi z}{2},z=2k+1\right)=\frac{2}{\pi}(-1)^{k+1} $$
it follows that:
$$ I = \frac{\pi}{2}\,\text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$
So we *may* consider every pole, but have to follow a slightly different approach from the usual one.

Comment: Thanks so much, @JackD'Aurizio :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses only a small bit of contour integration.
$$
\begin{align}
&2\operatorname{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{(i-1)x}(1-e^{-2x}+e^{-4x}-\dots)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\tag{1}\\
&=2\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac1{1-i}-\frac1{3-i}+\frac1{5-i}-\dots\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\dots-\frac1{-5-i}+\frac1{-3-i}-\frac1{-1-i}+\frac1{1-i}-\frac1{3-i}+\frac1{5-i}-\dots\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac12\frac{(-1)^k}{k+\frac12-\frac i2}\tag{4}\\
&=\frac\pi2\csc\left(\pi\left(\frac12-\frac i2\right)\right)\tag{5}\\
&=\frac\pi2\sec\left(\pi\frac i2\right)\tag{6}\\[2pt]
&=\frac\pi2\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac\pi2\right)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: the integral is twice that over half the range; the imaginary part vanishes
$(2)$: integrate each term; use contour integration to justify the imaginary exponent
$(3)$: add the conjugate to get twice the real part
$(4)$: write the sum compactly
$(5)$: $\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+z}=\pi\csc(\pi z)$
$(6)$: $\csc\left(\frac\pi2-z\right)=\sec(z)$
$(7)$: $\sec(iz)=\operatorname{sech}(z)$

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed alternative approach, @robjohn :-)